# How to fill input with button's innerText and also entered from the keyboard at the same time in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not sure it is a properly asked question but i couldn't set up the algorithm I mentioned in the title. I am beginner in React. I am so confused how to bind all of this stuff with hooks. I would like to thank you in advance, especially if you can help me on how to do the algorithm of the question I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function Component() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)} />

      <button onClick={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.innerHTML)}>First Btn</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.innerHTML)}>Second Btn</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for the answer Moein. I thought much more complex, it seems I should have thought much simpler.

Comment: Your welcome, it can be simpler even, if you write a function to prevent repeat same things again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle inputs like this in react :

```
 const [value , setValue] = React.useState('')

  const handleKeyPress = (e)=>{
    // some function based on your logic
  }

  <input 
  onKeyDown={handleKeyPress} onChange={(e)=>setValue(e.target.value)} 
  placeholder="Placeholder" value={value} ></input>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I think i asked wrong question because of my english. I have buttons and one input. I want to fill input with button's innerText and if user want to use keyboard it can work together. In short, I want filling input that can be entered both from the keyboard and by clicking the button.